# How can I build a Mac package on linux? (BOM file problem)

Tags: ios, macos, email, package, packagemaker

I'm running a business where we are creating email stationeries for people. We have some Mac users that currently have to download a zip file and manually copy that to their mail stationeries directory.

I want to automate that process and allow Mac users to download directly a package that will copy those files automatically.

I've build a sample package with PackageMaker, created script that will replace Archive.pax.gz with client's stationeries but go an error. I have realized I did not provide a mandatory BOM file. How can I create it on a non-mac platform? Or if I can't, is there any other way to create a Mac installer on a non-mac platform?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I've created a *postflight* hook that is doing all the installation process

Comment: Not a very helpful answer.  Where are the details?

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to create BOM (bill-of-materials) files on linux. Someone created an open-source version of mkbom at:

http://hogliux.github.io/bomutils

The website also has an easy to follow step-by-step tutorial on creating a Mac OS X installer on Linux ( http://hogliux.github.io/bomutils/tutorial.html ).

My company regularly build Mac OS X installers on linux with this method and so far we haven't had any major problems.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can find a package of this utility for your Linux: http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/8/mkbom/ or you can try to write it yourself, given the information available at Apple's website on BOM.

Comment: The sad thing is that Apple does not provide any information on the BOM format.  I've looked very thoroughly.  I'd love to be proven wrong.