# How to prepare a file for MacOSX that will be extracted to specific directory and nowhere else?

Tags: ios, zip, macos

We are running an business where we are preparing email stationeries for people. We want to make life easier for our Mac users to install their stationery in their mail application. The way we are doing that now is:
1. Prepare a zip file
2. Contact client, send a file, tell him where to extract that, repair any results of miscommunication and so on

We want to cut both points and allow him to go to our website, click a link and download an installer file, or self extracting zip, or whatever else that after double click will be extracted to appropriate path. Path is constant, it can be contained in some configuration file or even compiled with bytecode.

I've tried [preparing a custom package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116078/how-can-i-build-a-mac-package-on-linux-bom-file-problem) and [self-extracting zip archives](http://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/files/UnZip%206.x%20%28latest%29/UnZip%206.0/) without a success (in both cases there was a tiny details that made it impossible to get a result using that method). Do you guys have any other ideas?

Comment: You'll have to be specific about the issues you saw with those options, otherwise we'll just suggest them again :)

Comment: custom package - can't generate BOM file on linux (that's actually the problem described in the linked question by the way) ;;; 
self-extracting zip archives - can't prepare mac files on linux ;;; (our server is running on linux)
:P

Answer (score 1):

Here's some completely untested bash code you could have them run to download and unzip a file.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://www.yourserver.com/coolfiles.zip
unzip coolfiles.zip -d /path/to/installation/place
rm coolfiles.zip
```

Comment: actually thats so simple I didn't think about that before thanks! I'll check at the morning if mac have unzip by default and if yes it seems like you're the savior lol

Comment: Hey this is actually cool, theres just one glitch - I have no idea how to make it like 0777 immediately after downloading to allow some execution :-(